# Python: How to evaluate the residuals in StatsModels?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, patsy

I want to evaluate the residuals: (y-hat y).

I know how to do that:

```
df = pd.read_csv('myFile', delim_whitespace = True, header = None)
df.columns = ['column1', 'column2']
y, X = ps.dmatrices('column1 ~ column2',data = df, return_type = 'dataframe')
model = sm.OLS(y,X)
results = model.fit()
predictedValues = results.predict()
#print predictedValues
yData = df.as_matrix(columns = ['column1'])
res = yData - predictedValues
```

I wonder if there is a Method to do this (?).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

That's stored in the `resid` attribute of the [Results class](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.resid.html?highlight=resid#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.resid)

Likewise there's a `results.fittedvalues` method, so you don't need the `results.predict()`.

Comment: This does (currently) not work with the [RegularizedResults](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.base.elastic_net.RegularizedResults.html) class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a variety of (scaled) residuals such as externally/internally studentized residuals, PRESS residuals and others, take a look at the [`OLSInfluence`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence.OLSInfluence.html) class within `statsmodels`.

Using the results (a [`RegressionResults`](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults.html#statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResults) object) from your fit, you instantiate an `OLSInfluence` object that will have all of these properties computed for you. Here's a short example:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import OLSInfluence

data = sm.datasets.spector.load(as_pandas=False)
X = data.exog
y = data.endog

# fit the model
model = sm.OLS(y, sm.add_constant(X, prepend=False))
fit = model.fit()

# compute the residuals and other metrics
influence = OLSInfluence(fit)
```

Answer (score 1):

Normality of the residuals

**Option 1: Jarque-Bera test**

```
name = ['Jarque-Bera', 'Chi^2 two-tail prob.', 'Skew', 'Kurtosis']
test = sms.jarque_bera(results.resid)
lzip(name, test)
```

Out:

```
[('Jarque-Bera', 3.3936080248431666),
 ('Chi^2 two-tail prob.', 0.1832683123166337),
 ('Skew', -0.48658034311223375),
 ('Kurtosis', 3.003417757881633)]
Omni test:
```

**Option 2: Omni test**

```
name = ['Chi^2', 'Two-tail probability']
test = sms.omni_normtest(results.resid)
lzip(name, test)
```

Out:

```
[('Chi^2', 3.713437811597181), ('Two-tail probability', 0.15618424580304824)]
```